# I want to put the svg inside of the search box

Tags: html, css, angular, svg, search

- The svg image should inside of that of search input.
- Here i have made one form which is having one input and then there is a button which is showing the svg image.

[The Search bar Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg7cN.png)

```
    <form class="form-inline justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">



   <input style="width:400px ; margin-top:13px" (change)="SearchProduct($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchText"
    name="something" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search for queries & FAQs"
    aria-label="Search" />
 

  <button disabled style="height: 25px; width:30px" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21.679" height="21.679" viewBox="0 0 22.035 21.884">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .a {
            fill: none;
          }

          .b {
            fill: #959595;
          }
        </style>
      </defs>
      <rect class="a" width="21.679" height="21.679" />
      <path class="b"
        d="M21.7,20.726l-5.308-5.308a9.32,9.32,0,1,0-.92.92l5.308,5.308a.658.658,0,0,0,.46.194.638.638,0,0,0,.46-.194A.655.655,0,0,0,21.7,20.726ZM1.353,9.312a8,8,0,1,1,8,8.01A8.014,8.014,0,0,1,1.353,9.312Z"
        transform="translate(0.15 0.044)" />
    </svg></button>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the input search and the button inside a div instead and remove the input border then put a border to the div where those 2 elements are.

```
<div id="search-div">
    <!-- search input -->
    <!-- button -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#search-div {
    border: 1px solid #dee4e7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: I want that svg which is inside the button to come to the start or to come to end of the search . You can see the search in the image. I have tried using wrapper but it didn't worked as i wanted.